# Nginx reverse proxy: try multiple upstream servers in parallel and return the first successful response

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-upstreams

I've configured nginx as a reverse proxy for downloading software artifacts (e.g. JAR files) and want to speed it up by proxying each request to multiple upstream servers in parallel.

The following currently works: with nginx running at localhost:8080, I request `localhost:8080/com/foo/bar.jar`, nginx checks serially for the file `com/foo/bar.jar` at each host in a pre-configured list (e.g. `repo1.org/com/foo/bar.jar`, `repo2.org/com/foo/bar.jar`, etc.), and returns the first matching artifact (i.e. first to return status 200).

The config below makes this work for repos at maven.org and osgeo.org:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 8000;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 8001;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/;
        }
    }
    upstream repositories {
        server localhost:8000;
        server localhost:8001;
    }
    server {    
        location / {
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_404;
            proxy_pass http://repositories;
        }
    }
}
```

To decrease latency, I'd like for nginx to run the requests in parallel, return the first one that gives a 200, and otherwise return error code 404.

I'm not sure which directives (if any) can enable this kind of behavior. I appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

According to nginx documentation it is possible using nginx plus.
As stated in [nginx plus documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/choosing-nginx-plus-load-balancing-techniques/), the load balancing method you are searching for is the **Least Time** method.

If you are using the default nginx you can use [documentation nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

tldr;

- Default load balancing configuration (Round Robin)
- Least connected load balancing
- Weighted load balancing
- Session persistence